# Import pdf files from API into rows in Power Bi

Tags: r, powerbi, redcap

I have a Power Bi Dashboard I've made that pulls its Data from a Redcap Database using an API.  It looks like this, with mostly Text in the various columns:

[image]

What I'd love to do is make it so that thee fields circled in red were real files that could be clicked and downloaded.  I know that the API allows me to pull files from it.  I've used R with code like this (that individually mentions what record and field I want):

```
library(REDCapR)
redcap_download_file_oneshot( redcap_uri="https://redcap.company.org/redcap/api/", token="################", record="1", field='full_protocol_attachment_t_v2', event = "", repeat_instrument = NULL, repeat_instance = NULL, verbose = TRUE, config_options = NULL, overwrite = TRUE )
```

To individually download files one at a time.  The problem is twofold:

- If I were to use R, I have no idea how to automate that snippet of code for every row I may pull from the database (and if there are new rows)
- My understanding of PowerBi is that if I do use R, it makes refreshing the data harder when the report is published online. Right now given all the data just comes from an api directly into PowerBi, I don't have to setup any fancy permissions or gateways to have automated refreshes.

So my question is:  is there a way to do this directly within PowerBi?  Like a calculated column or something that would pull a particular records file based on what row it was in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can do in native PBI is have a URL which when clicked will open the destination for you. Can you create a full url for the file download?